# Is it a dependent clause?

Tags: clauses

> A team of epidemiologists at the University of Pittsburgh, for example, wondered if woman could avoid the increase in weight and cholesterol levels often associated with menopause.

1. Is the clause that starts with 'if' a dependent clause?
2. If woman could avoid the increase in weight and cholesterol levels, I can not realize what would happen?
3. If woman could avoid the increase in weight and cholesterol levels, weight and cholesterol levels are associated with menopause. Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it is a dependent clause. You have noticed that yourself by it becoming meaningless when considered as a sentence on its own.
2. This "if" is not used in an "if/then" context. It is paired with "wonder" to create the logical query about the truthfulness of the following condition. *To wonder if* is to ask the question: "Is this true?" The intention of the sentence is to indicate about what the team of scientists is curious.
3. No, this is not correct. The sentence in question makes no claim about the truthfulness, nor does it offer any conclusion. It only states that the scientists are curious about the truthfulness.

> A team of epidemiologists at the University of Pittsburgh --*subject*
>   wondered --*verb*
>   if women could avoid the increase in weight and cholesterol levels often associated with menopause. --*object*

There are weight and cholesterol levels associated with menopause. What did the team of epidemiologists at the University of Pittsburgh wonder about these levels? They wondered if women could avoid these levels.

Comment: Actually, I failed to clear my questions. My last question should be - What is the meaning of "if woman could avoid the increase in weight and cholesterol levels often associated with menopause."?

Comment: The _if_ in that sentence can be rewritten _whether or not_

Comment: Its meaning (as I described thrice) is to be the condition about which the scientists wonder.